# Sibling component not showing when called from a another sibling in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have read the forum but no luck with my issue. I opened a newsfeed screen as follows:
1.  screen launches a news component via a click 
2.  component only fetches data that is then passed to another sibling component ( to display the flatList items
3. From  an onPress event on an item should call and display  component for detail of item clicked.

The problem is that step 3 is not working.  I see the item highlighted when clicked and a diagnostic alert in the _onPress() do work. In debugging, I changed the onPress event to open the component directly using ... navigate('Newsdetail) but still no luck.
But when I replaced 'Newsdetail' with 'Home" (the main screen), that displayed the screen. I tried other components ('News') etc., nothing worked except for the  component. My code snippets and screenshots are shown below.  Please help as I have come to the end of my wits.  Thanks.

```
 import Newsdata from "../newsdata"; // import disabled for now until newsData component integration works


class News extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            news: [],
        };
    }


    getNews() {

        const link = 'https://feeds.feedburner.com/morganstateu';
        const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString; // convert xml data fetched to json object
        let resJson = [];

        return fetch(link)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then((response) => {

                parseString(response, function (err, result) {

                    resJson = result; // local var result saved to a global var resJson for later use


                });

                this.setState({news: resJson.rss.channel[0].item});


            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('fetch', err)
            });

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getNews();
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <Newsdata news = {this.state.news} navigation={this.props.navigation} />

        );


    }
}

export default News;
```

```
class Newsdata extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        newsItem: ''
    };
}

_onPress = (clickedItem) => {
    // this.setState({newsItem: clickedItem});
    // alert(clickedItem.description);

   return  <NewsDetail newsItem={clickedItem} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
};



render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    const  { navigate } = this.props.navigation;


    const textColor = this.props.selected ? "red" : "black";

    return (


        <Container style={styles.container}>
            <Content>
                <Header searchBar rounded style={styles.headerTitleStyle} iosBarStyle='light-content'>


                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Icon name="angle-left"  style={styles.headerIconStyle}/>
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>

                        <Item >
                            <Icon name="search" style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 25}}/>
                            <Input placeholder="Type Here..."
                                   onChangeText={(text) => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                                   value={this.state.text}
                                   underlineColorAndroid='transparent' />
                        </Item>
                    </Body>

                    <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Text>Search</Text>
                    </Button>
                    </Right>
                </Header>
                <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
                <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>


                    <FlatList
                        data={this.props.news}
                        extraData={this.state}
                         renderItem={({ item }) => (

                             <ListItem>
                                 <Thumbnail source={{uri: GetImage(item.description)}} />
                                 <Body style={styles.myListStyle}>
                                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress(item)} >


                                         <Text  style={{fontSize: 15}}> {item.title} </Text>
                                     </TouchableOpacity>

                                     <Text note >Posted:  {<TimeAgo time={item.pubDate.toString() }  />} </Text>

                                 </Body>
                                 <Right>
                                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('NewsDetail')} >
                                        <Button transparent>
                                            <Icon active name='angle-right' style={{fontSize: 30}} />

                                        </Button>
                                     </TouchableOpacity>
                                </Right>
                             </ListItem>
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
                        // onPressItem={this._onPress}
                        // refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        // onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                    />
                </List>

            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

}

export default Newsdata;
Screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tutAN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Vfl.jpg)

Dec. 18 Update:

I have done as advised. My _onPress() handler is returning the correct app state now with showDetails being null at app start and set to {item} on item click.  But no screen navigation is occurring er the logic in the code segment below. What am I doing wrong to make the screen navigate to the details screen (NewsDetail) upon item click?  Thanks for your help as I am stuck in neutral (smile).

```
<View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
                {this.showDetails
                    ? <NewsDetail showDetails={this.state.showDetails} navigation={this.props.navigation}  />
                    : <FlatList
                        data={this.props.news}
                        extraData={this.state}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (

                            <ListItem>
                                <Thumbnail source={{uri: GetImage(item.description)}}/>
                                <Body style={styles.myListStyle}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}>


                                    <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}> {item.title} </Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <Text note>Posted: {<TimeAgo time={item.pubDate.toString()}/>} </Text>

                                </Body>
                                <Right>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress(item)} >
                                        <Button transparent>
                                            <Icon active name='angle-right' style={{fontSize: 30}}/>

                                        </Button>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
                        // onPressItem={this._onPress}
                        // refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        // onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                    />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `_onPress` handler is not really an action, but a render function. This doesn't really do anything.

What you could do is store the clicked item in your state and depending on that you could render the details screen. Something like this:

```
_onPress = item => {
  this.setState({showDetails: item})
}

closeDetails = () => {
  this.setState({showDetails: null})
}

render () {
  return (
    <Container>
      {this.showDetails
        ? <NewsDetail newsItem={this.state.showDetails} />
        : {/* ... render List */}}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Imporant is, your action handler will not be called as a render function. So returning the JSX will not cause it to be rendered anywhere. Instead you need to handle the action in `_onPress` in a way that you can handle the new app state in the render function correctly.

Hope that makes sense :D

Comment: thanks for your response partner.  I will try it out and advise later. Cheers

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and now getting this error: Objects are not valid as a React child ... after I included the code snippet "{this.showDetails
        ? <NewsDetail newsItem={this.state.showDetails} />
        : {/* ... render List */}}" in the render() section. My original list is rendered under the <FlatList  /> component and not sure how to reference it in the second part of the above conditional test The test statement was entered as suggested after the <Container> section.  I have also defined the initial site of showDetails as null. Thx for your help.

Comment: I think I see what the problem could be.  The keyboard shortcut of applying comments unintentionally created an object {/* ...render list */} which is invalid. I need help on what to replace this conditional part with.  That is when showDetails state is null, how to instruct the program to render the <Flatlist /> which renders the list items. Please see location of this component in the render() portion of the code.  I am trying hard but not succeeding yet. I thought of separating it into another class object but then what will be in that class' render() section etc.  Thx

Comment: As I suspected, the comment caused the error as it went away after replacing it with a MyListItem class. Now I only get a blank screen without news item displayed.  But when i force the display by not commenting the <FlatList /> out in its original place, clicking a news item did nothing as before.